# Replace substring found in a list to another value in dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, replace

I have a bunch of words I want to replace to `""`. I put them in a list:

```
noise = [a,b,c,...]
```

Example dataset:

```
column1
I want a car
```

Becomes:

```
column1
I wnt cr
```

How can I use the list to iterate over in `replace` function.
This is my current code :

```
df[columnA] = df[columnA].str.replace((x for x in noise), "")
```

But I keep getting error.. I have to apply the same list to several other columns as well. So I'm looking for a shorter way to do this and avoiding `apply` function.

Error:

> TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

If add `len(noise)`, I'll get this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Unluckily there is not simple to replace many elements at once.

Comment: Bummer! I could use dict but I just thought it's ridiculous since I'm replacing them with same value.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:`df[columnA][i if i not in noise else ""]`

Comment: Will this apply to whole string or just substring? In my case, I'm looking for substring replacement